# New() in constructor

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me what New() in the following method constructor means?  I know that TEvent inherits from CompositePresentationEvent but what does new() mean?

```
protected void RaiseEvent<TEvent, TParameter>(TParameter parameter) where TEvent : 
    CompositePresentationEvent<TParameter>, new()
    {
        EventAggregator.GetEvent<TEvent>().Publish(parameter);
    }
```

Comment: Note that this method is not a constructor: **1.** You would not specify a return type with a constructor. **2.** You would not specify generic type parameters with a constructor; you would specify them at the type level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a constraint on the generic parameter of your method. It basically means that the generic type being passed as an argument to your method must have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 4):

In that function declaration `new()` is a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) on the `TEvent` generic type parameter. It means the type must be have a public constructor without parameters.

Read more about [constraints on generic types here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: Close - it means that the type can be created and must have a parameterless constructor.  You are thinking of the `class` constraint.

Comment: From the link you provided: "The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last."